# How to unclutter the form when a application has very many datasets

Tags: delphi, dataset, design-time

In a moderately complex database application in Delphi it's easy to have dozens of datasets (tables and queries) and associated datasources on a form.
All these clutter up the screen.
It gets worse when your form has a `pagecontrol` where every page has its own set of datasources et al.

If the Tables and Datasources were visual controls, at least they would only be visible on the Tabsheet where they're applicable.
I've thought about creating some container object that could hold many datasets and datasources, but never got round to it.

I also have `cnPack` which adds to option to hide non-visual components from view in the designer. 
However this is not helpful because it makes it hard to select them.

**What's the solution to unclutter the form designer whilst still having the option to select the data access components?**

*(For what it's worth I'm working in Delphi 2007 and XE2)*

Comment: It would be great if the structure pane had an option to **only** show non-visual controls.

Comment: If you have 'dozens of datasets' you may consider to manage them (create, ..free) by code.

Comment: @philnext, that will kill the benefit of **visually** designing a form.

Comment: Yes but I think that, if your application become complex, you have more advantages to manage by code or, even, consider an ORM.

Comment: You can always select them in the structure tree.

Answer (score 15):

You could create a data module for each logical group of non-visual components. Then name the data module accordingly so you can relate it quickly to the page the components belong to.

Comment: Yes, that works, but where did the data diagram go in Delphi 2007?

Comment: I tried this years ago, however the dataset components easily loose their connection to the (single) database connection component, if the datamodules are not opened in the correct order (after the datamodule which contains the connection).

Comment: Data modules, you gotta love them. :)

Comment: @mjn, if you got a single data module with a connection, you should create that first. If you create data modules on the fly (for instance, when you got an instance of a datamodule for each instance of a specific form), you will have to set the dataset property of the datasources from code. A small price for the gain of overview.   It is wise to keep the datasets on the datamodule and the datasources on the form. That way, you only have to link those two, and not every visual component, since they are linked to the datasource.

Comment: @mjn, I have had the same problem but found that if you close the offending files right away (they aren't saved by the IDE but aren't marked as changed either) and then reopen them, the connection is restored.

Comment: @Johan I don't know, where would you expect it to be? I can only check in D2009, though.

Comment: @Johan Oh and an alternative approach I sometimes use is making the form big at design time and group the non-visuals there, using e.g. labels as captions. Then I add some code to make the form right again at runtime (Size, alClient of main panel, ...). Not pretty, but sometimes the easiest way. I totally agree that being able to place them on individual pages right away would be great.

Comment: I would go with a single data module that maintains it's connections for the life of the app. Then your forms can simply call methods on that dm. I'd hate to create & destory a dm more than once in an app.

Answer (score 2):

[www.gexperts.org](http://www.gexperts.org) has a IDE plugin for delphi, which contains an option to hide/show all non-visual controls.

It is perfect for hiding all of the datasets etc so you can manipulate your components.  You can then show them again when you need to access them.

To make life even easier you can customize the toolbar so you can hide/show them in a single click.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own small expert or component (like [this one](https://github.com/DzmitryiK/TNonVisualCompList)) to hide nonvisual components you need and store them in groups.